# how to add all the cell value in c# with specific date

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Guys Help I want to add all the value with the same date and transfer to day sales  when i click the add, just all the value who has the same date, pls help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Buddy... **Stack overflow**  is the site where you need tricks to do not whole of the work for you as people do not have enough time... But, Here is the code so far which i think might help you.

```
private string _date = "";
private double _total = 0;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PopulateCombos();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
 }

private void PopulateCombos()
{
    try
    {
        PopulateEveryDay();
        PopulateDaySales();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
} 

private void PopulateEveryDay()
{
    dgvEvery.DataSource = null;
    DataTable dtEvery = new DataTable();
    dtEvery.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
    dtEvery.Columns.Add("total", typeof(double));

    DataRow dr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        dr = dtEvery.NewRow();

        dr[0] = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToShortDateString();
        if (i == 0)
            dr[1] = 100 * 1;
        else
            dr[1] = 100 * i * 2;

        dtEvery.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    dgvEvery.DataSource = dtEvery;
}

private void PopulateDaySales()
{
    dgvDaySales.DataSource = null;
    DataTable dtEvery = new DataTable();
    dtEvery.Columns.Add("date", typeof(DateTime));
    dtEvery.Columns.Add("total", typeof(double));

    DataRow dr = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        dr = dtEvery.NewRow();

        dr[0] = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-i).ToShortDateString();
        if (i == 0)
           dr[1] = 100 * 1;
        else
           dr[1] = 100 * i * 3;

        dtEvery.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    dgvDaySales.DataSource = dtEvery;
}


private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)dgvDaySales.DataSource;
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("date = '" + _date + "'");
        foreach (DataRow item in dr)
        {
            item["total"] = Convert.ToDouble(item["total"]) + _total;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}


private void dgvEvery_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        _date = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(dgvEvery.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["date"].Value).ToShortDateString());
        _total = Convert.ToDouble(dgvEvery.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["total"].Value);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```